# Relationship between Banach Space and Measurable Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

##### Motivation

I am asking this question because in the definition of a [Martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)#General_definition) on Wikipedia they define a random variable $f:\Omega\to S$ over a Banach space S. However typically one defines a random variable on a measurable space $(S, \mathcal{S})$.

> A Banach space is a complete metric space. Does it automatically induce a measurable space? What's the relationship between the two?

Comment: I am assuming there is an underlying probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. What I want to understand is this: given that $S$ is a Banach space, can we say that $(S, \mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space for some sigma-algebra $\mathcal{S}$ that is uniquely identified by the Banach space?

Typically one has a random variable from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ to $(S, \mathcal{S})$ where both are measurable spaces (and the first one has a probability measure on it)

Answer (score 4):

I think a natural measurable space can be made from any topological space $S$ by equipping $S$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets of $S$. This is usually what is meant in practice when we discuss $S$-valued r.v.s and $S$ has a topology, but there is otherwise no explicit mention of a $\sigma$-algebra.